# conditional multi-lingual laravel seeder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, multilingual

Suppose I have a table that contains a set of data in multiple languages and a foreign key `lang_code` referencing to the `code` on language table.

now I have to seed data table based on `lang_code` (en, es).
How do I make conditional seeder to seed based upon the foreign key value being assigned, i.e. if the `lang_code` is `en` then seeds in English and so on?

here is what I have on the dataTableSeeder

```
public function run(Faker $faker)
{
    $fakerEs = Faker\Factory::create('es_ES');
    $instructionIDs = DB::table('oes_instructions')->pluck('id')->toArray();;
    $languageIDs = DB::table('oes_languages')->pluck('code')->toArray();;

    foreach (range(1,4) as $index) {
        DB::table('oes_exam_instructions_data')->insert([
        'instruction_id' => $faker->randomElement($instructionIDs),
        'locale' => $faker->randomElement($languageIDs), 
        'content' => $faker->paragraphs(10, $asText = true),   
        //Here ho do i make this based on $languageIDs => $faker->paragraphs(10, $asText = true) 
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay was simple but i think it would be easier using Model Factory.

```
$fakerEs = Faker\Factory::create('es_ES');
    $instructionIDs = DB::table('oes_instructions')->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $languageIDs = DB::table('oes_languages')->pluck('code')->toArray();

    foreach ($instructionIDs as $instructionID) {
        foreach ($languageIDs as $languageID) {
            $data = ($languageID == 'en') ? $faker->paragraphs(6, $asText = true) : $fakerEs->paragraphs(6, $asText = true);
            DB::table('oes_instructions_data')->insert([
            'instruction_id' => $instructionID,
            'locale' => $languageID,
            'content' => $data,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);
        }
    }
```